# Almost serial downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/117002/balarka-sen?tab=reputation) user received 5 downvotes in less than a minute, in good answers, an apparently after some discussion with another user. I don't think this is fair game. Any mod can look into it?

Comment: The bot script ran in about 9:00 - 9:30 IST and the downvotes were all reversed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moderators don't have access to detailed enough vote information to do anything about such small issues, only SE employees have full access to the voting information. There is an automatic script that reverses serial voting that runs every night, just wait until it runs.

Comment: Do you think the system will see that? I wasn't sure if it was going to pick it up.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Nobody outside SE knows exactly how the script works, I'd guess that it will remove these votes if they are all from the same user, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @MadScientist When will it run, actually, in GMT? (I am asking because I leave on presumably almost the opposite side of the world)

Comment: @BalarkaSen 3:00 GMT as far as I remember

Comment: Would any action be taken against the user that serially downvoted some questions?

Comment: @BalarkaSen Generally not, unless the user makes a habit of doing this.

Comment: (I see it has been done so in this case...)